# more than one freeradius user and database

Tags: mysql, radius, freeradius

I want to make free radius managing system. 
there are many users who can use this system.
every user will have his own database.
for example, I have tow users the first one admin1 and the second admin2
the first user will have database1 and the second will have database2 
there is one online free radius server  which will be using for authenticating and accounting 
in free radius, as you know there is one sql.conf file which contains the database information 
I know I can make more than one instance of SQL for every user but when the system will have 100 users, for example, is this the right way to make 100 instances of database or there is another way to make this.
when the user open my online system he must have a new account when he click on register button he must insert his database information (host, username, password)
this information must go SQL.conf file in free radius to tell free radius to connect this database 
are there any one have an Idea about my problem 
I hope I explained my problem clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly, what you are looking for is to have a good performance radius database system. but on the face of it, what you have thought of doesn't sound a good idea. for the following reasons:

- over all maintenance becomes a huge issue for you.
- later on if you have to change the database to add or delete a field you have to do it on all the databases which is cumbersome
- taking reports on overall users and their status, consumption, service information will be difficult.

design the database well and you can use multiple modules to connect to it. you can write a python / perl programs for accounting module and sql module for authentication.

freeradius 3.0.x is shipped with rlm_rest module, where you can call a rest api for these purposes also. this gives you extreme power to manipulate with your data and would be even able to use BigData technologies also, which can easily handle the huge database overheads.

Comment: thank you very much about your reply but if I using just one database for all company that will make query from database more slow in other word if I have 100 company and every company has big number of user's that will make query from database take more time because as I said we will sell the system on cloud  .

Comment: but I don't understand what u mean about write python/perl program for accounting  . because I writing  the system using php language